# Rust/Serde/HTTP: Serialize `Option<http::Method>`

Tags: http, rust, serde

I am trying to set up serde with my Request struct to turn it into JSON to pass it to an api:

```rust
#[serde_with::skip_serializing_none]
#[derive(Serialize, Debug, Default)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct Request {
    #[serde(with = "http_serde::uri")]
    url: http::Uri,
    http_response_body: Option<bool>,
    #[serde(with = "http_serde::method")]
    http_request_method: Option<http::Method>,
}
```

I would like to have some fields as optional in the sense that if they are `None` then I just want to omit them from serialization. I am using `serde_with` to skip `None` fields, and it works for `http_response_body: Option<bool>` but not for `http_request_method: Option<http::Method>`. I am getting the following error:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src\zyte.rs:7:10
    |
7   | #[derive(Serialize, Debug, Default)]
    |          ^^^^^^^^^
    |          |
    |          expected struct `Method`, found enum `Option`
    |          arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected reference `&Method`
               found reference `&'__a std::option::Option<Method>`
note: function defined here
   --> C:\Users\isaac\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\http-serde-1.1.2\src\lib.rs:237:12
    |
237 |     pub fn serialize<S: Serializer>(method: &Method, ser: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Serialize` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `rust-simple-scraper` due to previous error
```

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the crate's `method::serialize` with your own function that takes `&Option<Method>`.

```rs
fn method_opt<S: Serializer>(method_opt: &Option<Method>, ser: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
    match method_opt {
        Some(method) => http_serde::method::serialize(method, ser),
        // This won't be encountered when using skip_serializing_none
        None => panic!("This should only be used with `serde_with::skip_serializing_none`"),
    }
}
```

Then use that for serializing.

```rs
#[serde(serialize_with = "method_opt")]
http_request_method: Option<http::Method>,
```

If you don't use `skip_serializing_none`, you can change the `None` branch to use `ser.serialize_none()`, but this will only work with simple formats like JSON. Formats that have different handling of `serialize_some` like [RON](https://github.com/ron-rs/ron) will end up inconsistent.

If you want to create both serialization and deserialization for this struct, you can create two functions in a module as described in the [serde documentation](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#with) [(example)](https://serde.rs/custom-date-format.html). This would have the same structure as the `http_serde::method` module.

Comment: The `Some` case should use [`serialize_some`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/trait.Serializer.html#tymethod.serialize_some). There are data formats where this is important and fail do deserialize otherwise.

Comment: @jonasbb Good catch, and the same remark applies to the second snippet in my answer! Note that it's not as easy as just calling `serialize_some()` - the whole point of this exercise is that the value you have is not `Serialize`, you have to call `http_serde::method::serialize()` which knows how to serialize it.

Comment: @jonasbb I think I've found a way to invoke `serialize_some()`, but it requires a newtype just for serialization.

Comment: Yes, it is a bit annoying to get `serialize_some` to work here, but it is important for proper data format support, e.g., with Ron. A newtype + `serde(transparent)` should work, or directly a custom `Serialize` implementation.

Comment: @jonasbb ah, that's good to know. I thought `Option` was just automatically flattened.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer covers only serialization, as asked in the question. This answer was written under the assumption that deserialization would also be needed. So if you need to combine `Option` with a type serialized/deserialized with a custom `#[serde(with = ...)]`, read on.

The simplest idea is to change the `#[serde(with = ...)]` to point to your own serializer/deserializer pair of functions, which delegate to `http_serde`. Deserialization requires a surprising amount of boilerplate due to having to implement a visitor, but since you already use the `serde_with` crate, you can use `serde_as` to eliminate some of the boilerplate.

Here is an implementation using the `serde_as`. It allows combining `Option` with a type that implements `SerializeAs`, and you can just create one that handles `http::Method`, and use it:

```
#[serde_with::serde_as]
#[serde_with::skip_serializing_none]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Default)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
pub struct Request {
    #[serde(with = "http_serde::uri")]
    url: http::Uri,
    http_response_body: Option<bool>,
    #[serde_as(as = "Option<AsHttpMethod>")]
    http_request_method: Option<http::Method>,
}

// Dummy type whose serialization delegates to http_serde::method
struct AsHttpMethod;

impl SerializeAs<http::Method> for AsHttpMethod {
    fn serialize_as<S: Serializer>(val: &http::Method, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        http_serde::method::serialize(val, serializer)
    }
}

impl<'de> DeserializeAs<'de, http::Method> for AsHttpMethod {
    fn deserialize_as<D: Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<http::Method, D::Error> {
        http_serde::method::deserialize(deserializer)
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation that uses just the `#[serde(with)]`, implementing a module with a serialize/deserialize pair that handles `Option<http::Method>`, also delegating actual serialization to `http_serde::method`:

```
mod option_http_method {
    use std::fmt;

    use serde::de::{self, Visitor};
    use serde::{Deserializer, Serialize, Serializer};

    // We need this wrapper so we can invoke serializer.serialize_some()
    #[derive(Serialize)]
    #[serde(transparent)]
    struct MethodSerialize<'a>(#[serde(with = "http_serde::method")] &'a http::Method);

    pub fn serialize<S>(option: &Option<http::Method>, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        match option {
            Some(method) => serializer.serialize_some(&MethodSerialize(method)),
            None => serializer.serialize_none(),
        }
    }

    pub fn deserialize<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Option<http::Method>, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        deserializer.deserialize_option(HttpMethodOptionVisitor)
    }

    struct HttpMethodOptionVisitor;

    impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for HttpMethodOptionVisitor {
        type Value = Option<http::Method>;

        fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
            formatter.write_str("an optional http::Method")
        }

        fn visit_none<E: de::Error>(self) -> Result<Self::Value, E> {
            Ok(None)
        }

        fn visit_some<D>(self, deserializer: D) -> Result<Self::Value, D::Error>
        where
            D: Deserializer<'de>,
        {
            let method = http_serde::method::deserialize(deserializer)?;
            Ok(Some(method))
        }
    }
}
```

Both approaches should provide equivalent functionality, with the first one having the advantage of brevity, at the cost of using `serde_with` "magic" (`serde_as` and the `SerializeAs` and `DeserializeAs` traits) compared to the serde-only approach of the second one. Note that, while both examples compile, I was unable to test them, as that would require constructing `http::Method` values.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a crate that provides the exact functionality you require. It allows using the http types wrapped in Option and other std collections.
https://crates.io/crates/http-serde-ext